# Swift 2 : Iterating and upper/lower case some characters

Tags: string, swift, swift2, uppercase

I want to modify a Swift string by converting some characters to uppercase, some others to lowercase.

In Obj-c I had following :

```
- (NSString*) lowercaseDestination:(NSString*) string {
    NSUInteger length = string.length;
    unichar buf[length+1];
    [string getCharacters:buf];

    BOOL up = true;
    for (int i=0; i< length ; i++) {
        unichar chr = buf[i];

        if( .... ) {
            buf[i] = toupper(chr);
        } else {
            buf[i] = tolower(chr);
        }
    }
    string = [NSString stringWithCharacters:buf length:length];
    return string;
```

How would you do that in Swift 2 ?

I did no find any `Character` method to upper or lower the case.

Would be an array of `String` of 1 character be an option ? (And then use `String` methods to upper and lower each `String`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`String` has a `upperCaseString` method, but `Character` doesn't.
The reason is that in exotic languages like German, converting a single
character to upper case can result in multiple characters:

```
print("ß".uppercaseString) // "SS"
```

The `toupper`/`tolower` functions are not Unicode-safe and not
available in Swift.

So you can enumerate the string characters, convert each character to
a string, convert that to upper/lowercase, and concatenate the results:

```
func lowercaseDestination(str : String) -> String {
    var result = ""
    for c in str.characters {
        let s = String(c)
        if condition {
            result += s.lowercaseString
        } else {
            result += s.uppercaseString
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

which can be written more compactly as

```
func lowercaseDestination(str : String) -> String {
    return "".join(str.characters.map { c -> String in
        let s = String(c)
        return condition ? s.lowercaseString : s.uppercaseString
    })
}
```

---

*Re your comment:* If the condition needs to check more than one
character then you might want to create an *array* of all characters
first:

```
func lowercaseDestination(str : String) -> String {

    var result = ""
    let characters = Array(str.characters)
    for i in 0 ..< characters.count {
        let s = String(characters[i])
        if condition {
            result += s.lowercaseString
        } else {
            result += s.uppercaseString
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Reminds me of the updates to `String` in Swift 2: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30

Comment: Supposing I need to lookahead 1 or 2 characters to determine my condition. How would that impact the function ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler: See update. The appended code resembles your Objective-C version more closely, so hopefully that helps to get you started.

Comment: *exotic languages like German* (used by 200m people) ; I like that :D Thanks for making me have great start of the day.

Comment: @JiriTrecak that's fun, huh? I speak ukrainian which is used by ~30 million people. German and Ukrainian combined is spoken by only 3.2% of earth population